# сломался range (python)

Tags: python, range

я шарпист, который периодически использует питоном, например для форматирования текста...
Тут вдруг такая ситуация, что питон (даже после переустановки) теперь считает range за класс, при этом не возвращая мне мой массив... Почему?
Тута консоль

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> range(100,0,-1)
range(100, 0, -1)
>>> type(range(100))
<class 'range'>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что в версии 3.x. это и есть объект. Чтобы получить список, нужно:

```
list(range(10))
```

Comment: Спасибо... Не помню что бы такое было в 3.8...

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей было-было

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей, такое поведение появилось в [Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, `range` в Python 3 - это бывший `xrange` из Python 2.7 (не знаю точно, с какой он там версии появился). Вдруг кому так понятнее будет. )